# Why is the last element of the array missing?

Tags: arrays, c, data-structures, append, missing-data

I have defined an array in C. I want to implement a code where I can insert a new value in the middle of array (anywhere inside the array except first and last position). So therefore I have written a function which will take three arguments - the array, the position where I want to put the new value, and the the value which will be inserted into the position. But when I am executing the program the last element is missing and it's showing the last value 5, but in the old array the last element is not 5. Can you please tell me where have I done wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void resize(int arr[], int position, int value);

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = { 10, 20, 60, 80, 10 };
    resize(arr, 3, 90);

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }
}

void resize(int arr[], int position, int value)
{
    for (int i = 5; i >= position; i--)
    {
        arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
    }
    arr[position - 1] = value;
}
```

Comment: Your array has space for 5 elements (since the size is taken from the size of the initializer).  But your loop attempts to write to 6 elements.  You're writing past the end of the array.  That's undefined behavior.  Hint:  The largest valid index is 4, not 5.  The 5 valid indices are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

Comment: In fact, the `printf`-loop in `resize` is also UB, as `i` will be 5 while `arr` only goes up to 4 (containing 5 elements).

Comment: Arrays in C cannot be resized like this. You need to either drop one of the elements of the array, or dynamically allocate memory

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso Thanks for all your help. I have solved it by allocating dynamic memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defined arrays cannot be *resized*. Allocated arrays can be reallocated.  You function `resize` has undefined behavior because it stores `arr[4]` into `arr[5]`, which is beyond the end of the array.

Here is a modified version that reallocates the array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int resize(int **arrp, size_t *countp, size_t position, int value);

int main(void)
{
    size_t count = 5;
    int *arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * count);
    if (arr == NULL) {
        printf("cannot allocate array\n");
        return 1;
    }
    arr[0] = 10;
    arr[1] = 20;
    arr[2] = 60;
    arr[3] = 80;
    arr[4] = 10;

    if (resize(&arr, &count, 3, 90) < 0) {
        printf("cannot resize array\n");
        free(arr);
        return 1;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf(" %d", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}

int resize(int **arrp, size_t *countp, size_t position, int value)
{
    size_t count = *countp;
    if (position > count)
        return -1;
    int *newarr = realloc(*arrp, sizeof(*newarr) * (count + 1));
    if (newarr == NULL)
        return -1;
    *arrp = newarr;
    *countp = count + 1;
    for (size_t i = count; i > position; i--) {
        newarr[i] = newarr[i - 1];
    }
    newarr[position] = value;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 10 20 60 90 80 10
```

Comment: Not that it probably makes one bit of practical difference in this case, but it might be worth freeing the dynamically allocated memory as a "good example."

Comment: @Chris: yes indeed. Answer amended.

Comment: @Chris yes! I tried it, and it works! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the previous code, and now it can add an value into desired position in the array.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int resize(int arr[], int array_size, int position, int value);
int main(void)
{
```

// initializing the size of the array by taking input from the user

```
    int array_size;
    printf("Enter array size: ");
    scanf("%d", &array_size);
```

// allocating space for the array

```
    int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * array_size);
    if (arr == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
```

// taking values for the array

```
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("enter: ");
        scanf("%d", (arr + i));
        i++;
    }
    while (i < array_size);
```

// printing the current array

```
    printf("old array: ");
    for(int j = 0; j < array_size; j++)
    {
        printf("%d, ", arr[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
```

// taking input for position

```
    int position, value;
    printf("position: ");
    scanf("%d", &position);
```

// taking input for value

```
    printf("value: ");
    scanf("%d", &value);
```

// incrementing the array size to the new size

```
    array_size++;
```

// resizing the array

```
    resize(arr, array_size, position, value);
```

// printing resized array

```
    printf("new array: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d, ", arr[i]);
    }
}    

int resize(int arr[], int array_size, int position, int value)

{
```

// allocating space for the new value in a different integer pointer

```
    int *arr1 = malloc(sizeof(int) * array_size);
    if (arr1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("error\n");
    }
```

// initializing all the value in arr1 is same as arr

```
    arr1 = arr;

    if (position == array_size)
    {
        arr1[position - 1] = value;
        arr = arr1;
        return 0;
    }
```

// shifting the array elements by 1 in the new array; which is ex: 4th position's element is now in 5th position

```
    else
    {
        for (int i = array_size - 1; i >= position; i--)
        {
            arr1[i] = arr[i - 1];
        }
```

// inserting the value in the position which is position - 1 index

```
        arr1[position - 1] = value;
```

// now again pointing the new arr1 to arr again so arr is now pointing to new updated memory

```
        arr = arr1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```